# iOS - iTunes Connect - Can't see existing external testers when submitting for review using TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I submitted a build on TestFlight, but the list of existing external testers isn't showing up. Instead, it showed a view saying `You haven't added any testers yet. Add testers.`

However I am certain that I've added external users and can be seen in `Users and Roles` section. I have tested app using TestFlight before without this issue. That was before the new grouping feature is out. Now I can add new testers manually but I have dozens of testers in existence so it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Am I missing something? Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution for this? Thanks!

[image: the selection list after clicking "Add Testers"]

[image: External users list not showing up]

Comment: Same issue here. Tried creating multiple groups and now all testers have disappeared from all groups and impossible to add existing users to a group. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 3):

The groups feature in iTunesConnect is clearly a little buggy.

I have had similar problems. I created a new external tester in the Users and Roles section and it DID NOT show up when I tried to add the new user to a group in the Test Flight section of the app. So I tried adding a "new" user with the "Add New User" toggle in your screenshot, with an identical email, first name, last name as the user I added in Users and Roles and that added the existing user to the group (did not create a duplicate in Users and Roles).

I thought a work around might be to download the CSV of your external testers and then "Import from CSV" to add those existing testers to the group. But that doesn't appear to work either as the downloaded CSV doesn't include all of the users for some reason (I'm guessing this is a bug but if someone else knows of a pattern I'm all ears)

Luckily adding NEW external testers to a group seems to work fine but if you want to add external testers from the Users and Roles section the only work around I've gotten to work is to add each user to the group as a "new" user making sure the email, first name, last name match.

Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: I find myself going through the same thing. This is honestly so ridiculous. Surely Apple should be fixing this bug ASAP. What's going on over there?

Answer (score 0):

[image: External Testers Group]

I think Apple added any existing external testers into a group called 'External Testers' on the left hand menu when they did the iTunes connect update last week to TestFlight. In this screenshot it's called 'Custom Group 1' but look for External Testers on yours.

You should then be able to rename the group, add/remove users from it etc? Can you see this group on the left hand menu?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find that group in the list. The menu looks like [this](http://imgur.com/a/ktS7Y). The `iTunes Connect Users` contains only `Internal Users`.